# Azure CPU % rising and never going back down

Tags: azure, cpu-usage

We've done a bunch of research on this already but haven't quite found another question like this on SO. We have an Azure website that runs normally for long stretches of time, then seemingly at random intervals the CPU will leap up all at once from an average of 5% CPU to 60% CPU and stay there (i.e. with hardly any ramp up at all). If left unattended, it will climb, hit the threshold where it adds another instance, and keep climbing thereafter. We crawl the entire site and we see no significant increase in CPU time after any specific request, and after looking at analytics have found that the sudden increase is independent of load, sometimes happens once a day, sometimes once every other day, and sometimes more than once a day.

To reiterate, this is not a CPU "spike" as it never goes back down. As you can guess, this is resulting in heavily delayed response times, up from an average of 100-200 ms per request to an average of 2-3 seconds per request.

We have found that recycling the site fixes the problem, and we are aware of several solutions that would allow us to recycle based off of memory usage, average request response time, among other triggers. However, we'd like to understand why this is happening and prevent it rather than potentially recycling several times a day.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What size are you using? At the peak time, can you find out which IP addresses are currently to the server?

Comment: @Win We can, but the CPU spike happens independent of load. It's almost seemingly at random. It isn't a traffic issue as when we recycle the application the CPU returns to normal percentages even at the same load as before it was recycled.

Comment: @JeffWebster we are seeing similar issues as well. Have you check your website logs/Trace for any "System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted." errors?